# Firebase AppCheck: how to remove/disable SafetyNet entirely from the UI when previously enabled (Firebase Bug?)

Tags: firebase, firebase-app-check, safetynet

We have both SafetyNet and Play Integrity enabled. We only want Play Integrity, but it’s currently impossible to disable SafetyNet from Firebase UI (looks like a Google bug!?).

SafetyNet reappears all the time when trying to enable Play Integrity and adding an SHA key.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with AppAttest for ios. Have you tried deleteing the app from firebase and putting it back ?